# Empty "using" statement in Dispose

Tags: c#

Recently I've seen some code written as follows:

```
public void Dipose()
{
   using(_myDisposableField) { }
}
```

This seems pretty strange to me, I'd prefer to see `myDisposableField.Dispose();`

What reasons are there for using "using" to dispose your objects over explicitly making the call?

Comment: Looks like the author thought he/she was being clever

Comment: I can't see any reasons to do this...

Comment: There's either some code missing, or someone needs to have their code reviewed more thoroughly until they learn how to write it properly.

Comment: No reason for a downvote IMO, +1 for what turned out to be quite interesting.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<strike>No, none at all. It will just compile into an empty `try/finally` and end up calling `Dispose`.</strike>

Remove it. You'll make the code faster, more readable, and perhaps most importantly (as you continue reading below) more ***expressive in its intent***.

**Update**: they were being *slightly* clever, equivalent code needs a null check and as per Jon Skeet's advice, also take a local copy if multi-threading is involved (in the same manner as the standard event invocation pattern to avoid a race between the null check and method call).

```
IDisposable tmp = _myDisposableField; 

if (tmp != null) 
    tmp.Dispose();
```

From what I can see in the IL of a sample app I've written, it looks like you also need to treat `_myDisposableField` as `IDisposable` directly. This will be important if any type implements the `IDisposable` interface **explicitly** and *also* provides a `public void Dispose()` method at the same time.

This code also doesn't attempt to replicate the `try-finally` that exists when using `using`, but it is sort of assumed that this is deemed unnecessary. As Michael Graczyk points out in the comments, however, the use of the `finally` offers protection against exceptions, in particular the `ThreadAbortException` (which could occur at any point). That said, the window for this to actually happen in is very small.

Although, I'd stake a fiver on the fact they did this not truly understanding what subtle "benefits" it gave them.

Comment: Strictly speaking, even that's not quite the same - what if another thread changes the value of `_myDisposableField` after the nullity check? You'd need to extract a local variable first...

Comment: @JonSkeet True. But then again, in both of these cases the commonality is to slap the developer responsible for doing this without comment.

Comment: I'm not sure how to parse that. Do you {slap them for doing this} without comment, or do you slap them for {for doing this without comment}? :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I'd say "{for doing this without comment} without comment" :)

Comment: @Jon Both, they deserve two slaps. Forehand and backhand :-P

Comment: Yes, it was used on single threaded code and seems to be one of the many quirks of the code base.

Comment: @DaveHillier Then although not technically equivalent, you can drop the `tmp` variable for semantically equivalent code in your case.

Comment: Perhaps then `using (var tmp = _myDisposableField) {}` would be the most/least clever approach?

Comment: @JonSkeet Turns out treating the variable as `IDisposable` is also important due to differences in implicit vs explicit interface definitions.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth There is one other important difference.  The OP's posted code will run `_myDisposableField.IDisposable.Dispose()` in a *protected section* (inside a finally block).  This means that it will not be interrupted by a `ThreadAbortException`, among other things.  Seems like this "clever" code is looking more **clever** by the minute.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk I don't think so personally, if it were that clever I'd expect to have seen it touted in an article somewhere. Also the OP specified that this isn't a multi-threaded app. I think it'd be more clever to wrap those protected sections yourself in order to make it perfectly understandable what is going on with it. Plus the window for that exception to cause any great behavioural difference is very small, the try-finally lives and dies within that one method call.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I agree that it is not a huge deal in most situations, but it is interesting to see yet another subtle difference between this and simply `_myDisposableField.Dispose();`.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk Indeed, and another good catch - I've amended my answer to provide the information.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very subtle but evil bug in the example you posted.

While it "compiles" down to:

```
try {}
finally
{
    if (_myDisposableField != null) 
        ((IDisposable)_myDisposableField).Dispose();
}
```

objects should be instantiated within the using clause and not outside:

> You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to the using statement, **but this isn't a best practice**. In this case, after control leaves the using block, the object remains in scope but probably has no access to its unmanaged resources. In other words, it's not fully initialized anymore. If you try to use the object outside the using block, you risk causing an exception to be thrown. For this reason, it's better to instantiate the object in the using statement and limit its scope to the using block.

—[using statement (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

In other words, it's dirty and hacky.

The clean version is extremely clearly spelled out on MSDN:

- if you can limit the use of an instance to a method, then use a `using` block with the constructor call on its border. Do not use `Dispose` directly.
- if you need (but *really* need) to keep an instance alive until the parent is disposed, then dispose explicitly using the [Disposable pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx) and nothing else. There are different ways of implementing a dispose cascade, however they need to be all done similarly to avoid very subtle and hard to catch bugs. There's a very good resource on MSDN in the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.100).aspx).

Finally, please note the following you should only use the `IDisposable` pattern if you use *unmanaged* resources. Make sure it's really needed :-)

Answer (score 2):

As already discussed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11778831/23354), this is a cheeky way of avoiding a null test, but: there can be more to it than that. In modern C#, *in many cases* you could achieve similar with a null-conditional operator:

```cs
public void Dipose()
    => _myDisposableField?.Dispose();
```

However, it is not required that the type (of `_myDisposableField`) has `Dispose()` on the public API; it could be:

```cs
public class Foo : IDisposable {
    void IDisposable.Dispose() {...}
}
```

or even worse:

```cs
public class Bar : IDisposable {
    void IDisposable.Dispose() {...}
    public void Dispose() {...} // some completely different meaning! DO NOT DO THIS!
}
```

In the first case, `Dispose()` will fail to find the method, and in the second case, `Dispose()` will invoke *the wrong* method. In either of these cases, the `using` trick will work, as will a cast (although this will do *slightly different things again* if it is a value-type):

```cs
public void Dipose()
    => ((IDisposable)_myDisposableField)?.Dispose();
```

If you aren't sure whether the type is disposable (which happens in some polymorphism scenarios), you could also use either:

```cs
public void Dipose()
    => (_myDisposableField as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
```

or:

```cs
public void Dipose()
{
    using (_myDisposableField as IDisposable) {}
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that when you have an explicitly implemented interface and another method of the same name, then it doesn't matter what you do, it's calling the wrong thing.

Comment: @DaveHillier for added fun, you could have `A : IDisposable { public void Dispose(); void IDisposable.Dispose(); }` and `B : A, IDisposable { public new void Dispose(); void IDisposable.Dispose(); }` :)

Answer (score -2):

The using statement defines the span of code after which the referenced object should be disposed.

Yes, you could just call a .dispose once it was done with but it would be less clear (IMHO) what the scope of the object was. YMMV.

Comment: I didn't downvote but my guess would be because your answer is about the using statement in general and not this specific situation where the OP is trying to replace an empty using with equivalent code.

Comment: The last line reads (and I quote): 'What reasons are there for using "using" to dispose your objects over explicitly making the call?'. Whoever downvoted clearly didn't read the question!

Comment: Yes but the scope plays no part in the reason for using a `using` here. The scope is a class member, the use of `using` doesn't make anything any clearer. Calling `Dispose` would actually make it clearer as `using` tends to be used for stuff that is declared, used and disposed in the same scope.