# Empty "using" block

Tags: c#, using

It has already been determined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778790/empty-using-statement-in-dispose) that an empty using block is not an appropriate way to override `Dispose()`, but what about the following case?

Is this a legitimate use for an empty `using` block?

```
try
{
    using (File.OpenRead(sourceFile)) { }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    error = "File not found: " + sourceFile;
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    error = "Not authorized to access file: " + sourceFile;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    error = "Error while attempting to read file: " + sourceFile + ".\n\n" + e.Message;
}

if (error != null)
    return error;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sourceFile);
```

Comment: You're just checking if you can access and read the file, you don't actually need the contents?

Comment: Since `using` basically expands to a `try { ... } finally { ... }`, what you're doing will result in something like `try { try { ...} finally { ... } } catch ( ... ) { ... } catch ( ... ) { ... } catch ( ... ) { ... }`.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff I excluded it for simplicity. Edited to provide a bit more context, but it's not relevant to the discussion.

Comment: @Dan context is almost always relevant :)  Why don't you just try to start the process and catch any exceptions there?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff Process.Start doesn't throw the same exceptions as OpenRead, so it's harder to determine what went wrong.

Comment: I'd be ok with it if you had a comment. Otherwise you [can use this pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/937558/119477)

Comment: @ConradFrix There are many other exceptions besides IOException that might be thrown.

Comment: @Dan. Yep so you'd have to add them. The point was that using the finally block might remove some of the smell of the `using` inside a `try`

Answer (score 3):

No it's not a legitimate use for an empty using block.

You can simply write the try like this:

```
try
{
    File.OpenRead(sourceFile).Close();
}
```

Either `OpenRead()` will succeed and return a stream that you must close (or dispose, but I think .Close() better expresses your intent), or it will thrown an exception and not return anything.

Therefore you can always just close the returned value.

(I assume that you are just checking for read access before doing something else. However, be aware that you could in theory have a race condition because the accessibility of the file could change between you making this check and later on actually opening the file. This is unlikely to happen in practice, but you should be aware of the possibility.)

Comment: But if `OpenRead` throws it gets not closed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If `OpenRead` throws, it doesn't get opened so there's nothing to close.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If `OpenRead()` throws, the file didn't get opened and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: ah ok, but personally i find this not readable. It's not obvious on the first sight that this cannot cause an open resource. That's why i also prefer a using (or try-catch-finally) here. I would also use `using (MethodThatReturnsDisposable()){ }` because the execution of the method could be important but i don't want to consume the returned disposable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It really should be obvious though - you should know that `File.OpenRead()` only ever returns a non-null value. And if you know that, you should also know that you can always safely close it. If you don't know that, then do you check its return value for `null` before using it? Because if you are saying that it's not obvious that `OpenRead()` cannot return null then you would presumably be writing code that checks the return value for null... Like Tigran did in his code sample above.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: i haven't said that it's not obvious that it cannot be `null`, i've said that i must give it some thought to notice that this will close always and only if there is no exception and the object is not null. It's obvious now, yes. What i also like with the `using` is that it is not a method like `Close` where you need to think about null or not null. The intent is clear, call the method, do nothing with the returned object, ensure that it gets disposed always.

Answer (score -1):

Not much sense in using empty `using` block, as you simply can add finally at the end of `catch` chains and handle `Dispose` there:

```
FileStream fs;
try {

    fs = File.OpenRead(sourceFile); 
}
catch(..) {
}
catch(..) {
}
catch(..) {
}
finally {

  if(fs !=null) {
      fs.Close();
      fs.Dispose();

  }
}
```

Comment: This still seems incredibly pointless as all he's seemingly trying to do is see if the file exists and he has access to it. Not a good use of `OpenRead`.

Comment: @DaveZych: seems it's not *only* for checking presence of file. but more, in this case you have also possible feedback about a cause of the problem.

Comment: @DaveZych It checks for any errors that would prevent the user from reading the file, not _just_ `File.Exists()`.

Comment: Note that this code won't actually compile unless you initialise `fs` to null.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: yes, also you can not use catch(..). this is just a pseudocode, to provide an idea.